# Showing java output in browser

Tags: java, batch-file

I have a java class which when we run, a batch file will be executed. I have a variable `isSuccessful` (boolean) which will display either true or false indicating if the batch file executed its command correctly or incorrectly. Now, the true or false output is only shown in the console. I want it to be displayed on the web browser when i type in a URL (e.g. `localhost:8080/runbatchfile`)

So far i have these codes:

**RunBatchfile.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class RunBatchFile {

@Test
public void RunningBatchCommand() {

    String filePath = "C:/Users/attsuap1/Desktop/test.bat";
    try {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filePath);

        int exitVal = p.waitFor();

        boolean isSuccessful = true;

        if (exitVal == 0)

        {
            isSuccessful = true;
        } else {
            isSuccessful = false;
        }

        System.out.println(isSuccessful);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

**BatchFile.java**

```
public class BatchFile extends RunBatchFile {

private static String isSuccessful;

public BatchFile(String isSuccessful) {
    this.isSuccessful = isSuccessful;
}

public static Object getIsSuccessful() {
    System.out.println(isSuccessful);
    return isSuccessful;
  }
}
```

This BatchFile.Java class gives me this error:

> java.lang.Exception: Test class should have exactly one public
>   zero-argument constructor     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateZeroArgConstructor(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:171)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.validateConstructor(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:148)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.collectInitializationErrors(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:127)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.validate(ParentRunner.java:416)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.(ParentRunner.java:84)   at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:65)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:138)
>     at
>   org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner.(SpringRunner.java:49)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:84)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)

**BatchFileController.java**

```
@RestController
public class BatchFileController {

private static final String template = "Result, %s";
private static String getIsSuccessful;

@RequestMapping("/runbatchfile")
@ResponseBody
public BatchFile batchFile(@RequestParam(value = "result") String result) {
    return new BatchFile(String.format(template, result));
  }
}
```

**Application.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```

I am new to this. I tried what i can. Someone please help me to correct my codes. Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you please paste the exception that you are getting?

Comment: @Waqas Hi, done it

Comment: How are you calling your "contextLoads()" method? I don't see it being called from the "BatchFile" class

Comment: That was the method i created first which i learnt from a tutorial before creating BatchFile class. What should i change the contextLoads to?

Comment: The RunBatchFile.java class alone works and does what it is supposed to do. However since now i have to show the output in a browser, i created a new class BatchFile.java. Now i am not sure how to link these two files.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new constructor in `BatchFile` which will call the method `contextLoads`. And have your `BatchFileController` class call this new constructor instead.

I would also suggest removing all the annotations you have from `RunBatchFile`, since those are for Junits and it is why you're getting the exception.

Comment: This is what i want:

`Create a new constructor in BatchFile which will call the method contextLoads` but i am not sure how to do it. Can you please guide me abit more in this